# im looking for a music type but i cannot find it

Tags: musical-forms

im not so much into music i don't even know what is the difference between pop and rock but recently i've been making movies and uploading them to youtube and i need music for my movies i often used video games musics but now i need something that i can't find. do you know what i mean? i mean there are some musics in some movies or video games where men sing HOOOOOO with an epic voice and its kinda emotional. i can't really explain it but here's an example:

you see? in this music men sing emotional and i want the name of this music type tnx

Comment: Do you mean male choir?